# Simplify star rating code

Tags: php, html

I'm currently working on a rating system for a website but I'm stuck with the conditional statements in RAIN Language. I have 2 questions:

- Is there a way to make this piece of code more efficient?
- Is it a problem to leave it like this or will it slow down the loading speed of a website?

  ```
    <div class="product-rating">

      {% if (product.score * 5) < '1.3' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '1.3' and (product.score * 5) < '1.7' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '1.7' and (product.score * 5) < '2.2' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '2.2' and (product.score * 5) < '2.7' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '2.7' and (product.score * 5) < '3.2' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '3.2' and (product.score * 5) < '3.7' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '3.7' and (product.score * 5) < '4.2' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '4.2' and (product.score * 5) < '4.7' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
      {% endif %}

      {% if (product.score * 5) > '4.7' %}
      <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
      {% endif %}

    </div>
  ```

Comment: store the value of product.score * 5 into a variable, also you can make use of switch case or else if, you don't need to check (product.score * 5) with the following if statements if one condition went true

Comment: You are missing all numbers which you have set. 
1.3, 1.7, 2.2.. because at both places < > you don't put equal  = and this means that on each of those numbers, it wont be at any of those cases..

Comment: `round (product.score*10)/2` will give you the "rating" you need. Then, you should be able to produce the stars with a loop instead.

Comment: Change it to an iterate statement between 1.3 and 4.7 with a 0.5 increment with product.score as the max. If in .3 to .7 range add '-half-o' to the one class else add star.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this (not sure if there are syntax problems as I wrote it here..
The thing I change is that numbers are now not strings and I don't skip all numbers which you have set for ranges.
Using elseif confirms that the calculation is bigger than the previous IF. So there shouldn't be any problem. 
+ This calculation score*5 can be made before the how IF statement as somebody purposed.

```
<div class="product-rating">

    {% if (product.score * 5) < 1.3 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 1.7 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 2.2 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 2.7 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 3.2 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 3.7 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 4.2 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>
    {% elseif (product.score * 5) < 4.7 %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
    {% else %}
    <i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i>
    {% endif %}

  </div>
```

Comment: This seems to be working great. The problem I encountered was a syntax error on <= statements.

Answer (score 1):

It's better to implement a function to draw the score, something like this *without templating* :

```
function drawScore($score){
    $solid = floor($score);
    $empty = 4 - $solid;
    $half =  $score - $solid;
    for($i = 1; $i <= $solid; $i++){
        echo '<i class="fa fa-star"></i>';
    }
    if($half > 0){
        echo '<i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>';
    }
  for($j = 0; $j < $empty; $j++){
    echo '<i class="fa fa-star-o"></i>';
  }
}
```

Then all you need inside `<div class="product-rating">` is to call the function like:

```
$pScore = $product.score * 5;
drawScore($pScore);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a method using a for loop.

```html
<div class="product-rating">
  {% if (product.score * 5) < 1.3 %}
   <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  {% endif %}

#  array = [1.3,2.2,3.2,4.2]
{% for item in array %}
  {% if if (product.score * 5) > item  %}
   <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  {% elseif (product.score * 5) < (item + 0.5) %}
   <i class="fa fa-star-half-o"></i>
  {% endif %}
{% endfor %}


  {% if (product.score * 5) > 4.7 %}
   <i class="fa fa-star"></i>
  {% endif %}
</div>
```